# AlamofireObjectMapper not installing properly

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

Using Xcode 7.1, Cocoapods 0.39.0 (latest version)

Tried installing AlamofireObjectMapper using Cocoapods and followed directions from [GitHub](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

Below is the code for my PodFile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 0.7'
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 0.15'

target 'CP3' do
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git',:branch => 'xcode7'
end
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

**ERROR**

[image]

The weird part is that if I just comment the '**AlamofireObjectMapper**' line in **Podfile** then everything else (SwiftJSON, ObjectMapper & Alamofire) runs fine. Not sure why its happening.

Comment: I just tested this. Worked but I had to do:  `pod repo remove master` `pod setup` `cd ~/Desktop/TestApp` `pod install`. After that it installed fine. Before that it would not install :l

Comment: tried this..but it did not work..not sure why? same error is showing...just to check...the first 2 commands ---which directory did you write them in. I tried within the app's directory..it didn't work..then I tried it outside on the Users directory..still didn't work..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the cocoapods using

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Reinstalled everything. Finally worked.